# How to add multiple workspaces in Unity 2D?

Tags: workspaces, unity-2d

In Unity 2D there isn't any multiple workspaces. How can add more than that 1?

Answer (score 12):

**Update**: Unity 2D now has workspaces, see this [Omg!Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/workspaces-come-to-unity-2d/) post for more info.

[You can set them as described in this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95057/only-1-workspace-in-unity-2d)

[image]

---

From the Unity 2D announcement [blog post](http://bfiller.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/unity-2d/):

> In it’s current state, many of Unity’s features from Maverick have already been implemented (dash, places, launcher, panel) and others (uTouch, **workspace switcher**, accordion effect, etc) will be landing over the next few months.

<sup>(Emphasis mine).</sup>

Unity 2D does not yet support workspaces, but it will in the near future.

Answer (score 7):

Update for GUI solution

#### Unity-2D with 4 workspaces (default)

[image]

#### Change the number of workspaces

To change the number of workspaces edit **metacity** settings, e.g. by running `gconf-editor` [image: Install gconf-editor] and change setting in `/apps/metacity/general`:

[image]

#### Restart metacity so changes take affect.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type in `metacity --replace`

Your computer will have a temporary seizure, then it will be back to normal - but with added workspaces!

#### Unity-2D workplace-switcher using 6 workspaces

[image]

Comment: Does this still work for 11.10?

Comment: @jrg: yes, this still works in 11.10 for Unity2D.

Comment: I tried this, but even after the replace I get my old four workspaces.

Answer (score 5):

Execute in terminal:

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces --type int $x
```

where you replace `$x` with the number of workspaces you want!

For example:

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces --type int 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a very recent change, but my Unity 2D supports workspaces. I don't have the 'Workspace Switcher', as referenced in DoR's response, but I do have workspaces. I navigate them via hot keys I setup in 'Keyboard Shortcuts'.