# How configure workspaces on Unity-2D?

Tags: unity-2d

I don't know what I did exactly, but when my touchpad "froze" (another story) I started to make random combinations with the keyboard, and seems that accidentally I deleted my workspaces. I had 4, and now I only have 1. It's curious, but on Unity-3D, the 4 workspaces still there (cause it's use compiz, no?).

Well, how can I restore my workspaces?

Regards.

Edit: Ok, tried to do what says in this thread [How to add multiple workspaces in Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21755/how-to-add-multiple-workspaces-in-unity-2d) but don't work for me :(

On the dconf editor, in the /apps section, it doesn't shown /metacity, but I have it installed!

Comment: /apps/metacity is only available in gconf-edit ... I tried 'gconftool-2 -s /apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces --type int 5'  on Unity 2D on 11.10 and I was able to set the number of workspaces to 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/apps/metacity` is only available in gconf-edit ...

I tried `gconftool-2 -s /apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces --type int 5` on Unity 2D on 11.10 and I was able to set the number of workspaces to 5.

Comment: Worked for me on 12.04 Beta 1, as well, after a bug where GNOME Shell affecting the number of Unity 2D workspaces was fixed and I was stuck with only one. Thanks much!