# How to personalize number/arrangement of workspaces?

Tags: unity, compiz, workspaces, gconf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)

I want to set 6 horizontal workspaces on my Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity.

The "solutions" suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66701/how-configure-workspaces-on-unity-2d) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21755/how-to-add-multiple-workspaces-in-unity-2d) do not allow me to arrange them in complete horizontal fashion.

I remember doing this in a previous version of Ubuntu with Unity but I couldn't find the right option in the System Settings or CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **"CompizConfig Settings Manager"** got to General Options > Desktop Size tab

[image]

[image]

Then you can set the **Horizontal Virtual Size** to **6**

Hope this will helpful!.

Comment: Awesome. That is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Tweak lets you modify the number both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However I couldn't find it in the Ubuntu Software center. Is it compatible with Unity?

Comment: Yes it is. I got it from the ppa as described here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/ubuntu-tweak-gets-full-ubuntu-1210.html