# Only 1 workspace in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-2d, workspaces

I'm using Unity 2d.

When I click on Workspaces, it zooms out, but the screen is black where the other 3 workspaces should be. When I try clicking in the black area, nothing happens.

Answer (score 7):

By default the # of workspaces would be 4 & typically nothing would change that setting on it's own.

However if you did happen to login to gnome-shell, -  when exiting GS it writes to gconf the # of workspaces open at exit which many times is 1. This then would affect the # available to unity-2d.

Here's a bug on this behavior  -

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/826089

In any event you can set the # of workspaces for unity-2d thru gconf, from a terminal you'd run this command

```
gconftool-2 -s -t integer /apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces 4
```

Alternately if you have gconf-editor installed you could open it & browse to /apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces & adjust there.